# Кодировка ASCII в Xcode

Tags: xcode, c++

В Xcode при вводе русского символа в переменную типа char, если сразу же вывести эту самую переменную, выводит \320 или что-то похожее.

Я так понимаю, это потому, что он использует utf.

Как заставить его работать с ascii кодировкой? Помогите, а то лабу все никак сдать не могу. (

Answer (score 1):

Метод возвращает указатель на С строку:

```
 NSString *string = @"Я";
 const char *cString = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
```

[image]

**UPD**

```
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::string stroka;
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.1251") ;
    std::cout << "Введите строку==>> ";
    std::getline (std::cin,stroka,'\n');
    std::cout << "\n Вот ваша строка=====";
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus_rus.866");
    std::cout << stroka <<'\n';
    std::system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно (( просто нужно, чтобы было, как в винде, если говорить уж совсем по-деревенски.  
То есть как-то включить ascii кодировку, чтобы весь текст, с которым он работает, что в консоли, что записываемый в файл был в ascii. Извините за сумбурность.

Comment: Вы простите, конечно, но Ваш вопрос и данный коментарий звучит как: "Как создать атомную бомбу, если мама варит кофе - бегемоты бегают стаями?"  И поэтому я вынужден задать уточняющий вопрос к последнему комментарию: "Вам нужно, чтобы xCode работал с файлами в кодировке ASCII вместо UTF-8 (что по умолчанию)?".

Comment: Ахах, ну да

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Результат тот же. Выставлял и Non-lossy ASCII, и windows cyrillic, и все, что связанно с кириллицей.  
Все равно вот эта программа:

    char a;
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cout<<a;

при вводе любой русской буквы  выводит \320 или \321

Comment: Подразумевая данный комментарий, я обновил ответ, не знаю, насколько он корректен, просто погугил.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, конечно, но все равно не помогло, лучше винду виртуалкой накачу.